# activityStartTrigger: not whiteListe while signing in with google

Tags: java, android, firebase-authentication

I have implemented the google signin in my app, In the debug app signin works fine but in signed apk getting the following error.

```
12:53.171 1556-2063/? E/ActivityTrigger: activityResumeTrigger: not
whiteListedin.greylabs.beacondriverlite/in.greylabs.beacondriverlite.activities.user_login_reg.LoginActivity/1
2019-04-15 13:12:53.172 1556-2063/? D/ActivityTrigger:
activityResumeTrigger: The activity in ApplicationInfo{7a11681
in.greylabs.beacondriverlite} is now in focus and seems to be in
full-screen mode 2019-04-15 13:12:53.172 1556-2063/?
E/ActivityTrigger: activityResumeTrigger: not


whiteListedin.greylabs.beacondriverlite/in.greylabs.beacondriverlite.activities.user_login_reg.LoginActivity/1
```